# Why does JS refresh properly in all browsers except IE?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, refresh

I need the page to reload every 8 seconds. It works just fine in Chrome, Firefox, and Safari, but in IE, it stops refreshing after anywhere from 1 to 12 refreshes. That is problematic.

The following part is included in the head of the document. getScrollXY gets the page coordinates so that the iframe can be reloaded at the exact some position. The three d variables are the X value, the Y value and the form. The here PHP variable is the page's URL, obviously, modified as needs be.

```
function unloadP(dung,dong,dang)
{
    s=getScrollXY();
    document.getElementById(dong).value = s[0];
    document.getElementById(dang).value = s[1];
    document.getElementById(dung).submit(); 
    return false;
    window.location = \"$here\";
    window.location.reload(true);
}

function unloadPnow(dug,dog,dag,deg)
{
    s=getScrollXY();
    document.getElementById(dog).value = s[0];
    document.getElementById(dag).value = s[1];
    document.getElementById(dug).submit(); 
    return false;
    window.location = deg;
    window.location.reload(true);
}
```

And this is where the action actually happens.

```
if(isset($newscroll))
{
    if(count($printlast)!=0)    $_SESSION['printlast']=$printlast;
    $_SESSION['newscroll']="isset";
    if($newscroll!="set")   $here='http://127.0.0.1/dummyname.php?ord=1&mode='.$newscroll;//#duh';
    if(strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],"Safari")!==FALSE)
        {
            print("<body onLoad=\"setTimeout('unloadP(\'thisf\',\'scrollx\',\'scrolly\')', 100);\">
                <form id=\"thisf\" method=\"post\" action=\"$here\">
                <input type=\"hidden\" name=\"scrollx\" id=\"scrollx\" value=\"3\">
                <input type=\"hidden\" id=\"scrolly\" name=\"scrolly\" value=\"4\"></form>");
        }
    else
        {
            print("<body onLoad=\"setTimeout('unloadP(\'thisf\',\'scrollx\',\'scrolly\')', 0);\">
                <form id=\"thisf\" method=\"post\" action=\"$here\">
                <input type=\"hidden\" name=\"scrollx\" id=\"scrollx\" value=\"3\">
                <input type=\"hidden\" id=\"scrolly\" name=\"scrolly\" value=\"4\"></form>");
        }
}
else
{
    if(isset($_SESSION['printlast']))   unset($_SESSION['printlast']);
    if(!isset($dontload))
        {
            if(isset($_POST['scrollx']))
                {
                    print("<body onLoad=\"loadP(); setTimeout('unloadP(\'thisf\',\'scrollx\',\'scrolly\')', 8000);\">
                        <form id=\"thisf\" method=\"post\" action=\"$here\">
                        <input type=\"hidden\" name=\"scrollx\" id=\"scrollx\" value=\"3\">
                        <input type=\"hidden\" id=\"scrolly\" name=\"scrolly\" value=\"4\"></form>");
                }
            else
                {
                    print("<body onLoad=\"window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight); window.top.scrollTo(0,0); setTimeout('unloadP(\'thisf\',\'scrollx\',\'scrolly\')', 8000);\">
                    <form id=\"thisf\" method=\"post\" action=\"$here\">
                    <input type=\"hidden\" name=\"scrollx\" id=\"scrollx\" value=\"3\">
                    <input type=\"hidden\" id=\"scrolly\" name=\"scrolly\" value=\"4\"></form>");
                }
        }
    else
        {
            print("<body onLoad=\"window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight); window.top.scrollTo(0,0); setTimeout('unloadP(\'thisf\',\'scrollx\',\'scrolly\')', 8000);\">
                    <form id=\"thisf\" method=\"post\" action=\"$here\">
                    <input type=\"hidden\" name=\"scrollx\" id=\"scrollx\" value=\"3\">
                    <input type=\"hidden\" id=\"scrolly\" name=\"scrolly\" value=\"4\"></form>");
        }
}
```

Thank you for your time.

Edit: As the first comment suggested, I tried setting cache-control headers, but it did not help. The headers are:

```
header('Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate');
header('Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT');
header('Pragma: no-cache');
```

Also, for the record, I tried changing the value of a GET variable on each refresh to trick IE into thinking it was another page, to no avail. I even duplicated the code and put it in another page, switching from one to the other on each refresh, but that did not keep IE refreshing either. My guess is either a small error in the syntax tolerated by every other browser, or that IE is actively blocking refreshes.

Comment: Are you setting the correct caching headers?

Comment: I just set the following headers, to no avail.

header('Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate');
header('Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT');
header('Pragma: no-cache');

Comment: Doesn't the expire date have to be in the future

Answer (score 0):

Another option apart from what has already been suggested is adding a random variable attribute you your url so that to differentiate the link from whatever value IE browser may have cached.

Comment: I already do that with a $_GET variable. It switches from 0 to 1 or from 1 to 0 on every load.

Comment: In fact, at one point, I even duplicated the page and gave it another name and switched between the two pages at every refresh. IE randomly stopped refreshing anyway.